# Obtener Email usando el Api de paypal

Tags: php, api, paypal

Estoy generando pagos, en este caso mi plataforma utiliza los datos del usuario registrado (nombre, email), al generar la orden agrego esa innformación con:

```php
$payer = new Payer();
$payer_info->setEmail($email);
$payer->setPayerInfo($payer);
```

Ahora supongamos que el usuario al pagar logea una cuenta que no necesariamente tiene el mismo correo que se encuentra registrado en el sistema, entonces a la hora de aprobar el pago regresa un payload con la información del pago la pregunta es: ¿Como obtengo el correo que se paso por payerinfo y no el correo con el que se tenia registrada la cuenta?? es posible hacer eso o necesariamente tendría que consultar a BD para obtener la información de mi pago (email)
?

Se supone que se tendría que obtener en ese lado (ver la imagen),
¿En entornos de producción si muestra el correo que configuras por payerInfo o sigue regresando el correo de la cuenta con la que pago?

por que en modo sandbox no tiene ningún efecto agregar el payerInfo.

Gracias!

[image: Payload]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La info de PayerInfo que viene como respuesta de un pago es el email de la cuenta que se realiza la transaccion.

La llamada a `$payer_info->setEmail($email);` permite seleccionar de antemano una cuenta paypal por su correo electronico, pero el usuario puede no tener una cuenta con dicho correo, y cambiar a otra cuenta/email para realizar el pago. Este es el correo que se recibe en `payer_info.email`

Si deseas mantener la relacion entre la cuenta final que paga la transaccion y el usuario asociado a ella puedes mantener esta informacion en la sesion de pago y utilizarla al recibir la verificacion de la transaccion. (y podrias almacenar el correo paypal de pago en algun registro del usuario para futuros pagos)

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, Claro lo que pasa es que necesitaba el correo para que una ves que llegue el payload poder enviar un correo al usuario con los detalles del pago pero a vista que el correo puede ser otro como tu lo mencionas mejor optaré por consultar a mi base de datos con el id de referencia alli mismo podré obtener todos los datos sobre la orden y el usuario. muchas gracias por la aclaración
Estaría bueno obtener el correo que configuraste desde que creaste la orden puesto que con ese payload podría construir perfectamente un correo de confirmación y ahorrar una consulta aBD